# Org babel remove currency form ledger output

Tags: org-babel, ledger

Howto remove the currency from the table or get ledger -j to work so that gnuplot can work with the data?

```
#+NAME: LedgerCli
#+BEGIN_SRC ledger :results raw :cmdline reg "Assets:Service Days" --exchange sd --format='| %D | %t | \n'
SOME LEDGER STATEMENTS

#+END_SRC
#+Name: ledgercli-table
#+RESULTS: LedgerCli
| 2019/12/01 | 12.0 sd |
| 2019/12/03 | -0.5 sd |
| 2019/12/05 | -0.5 sd |
| 2019/12/10 | -1.0 sd |
| 2019/12/17 | -1.0 sd |
| 2020/03/23 | -4.0 sd |
| 2020/04/01 | -0.1 sd |
| 2020/05/19 | -0.5 sd |
| 2020/05/26 | -0.3 sd |

#+begin_src gnuplot :var data=ledgercli-table :file gnuplot.png :exports results
  set xdata time
  set style data linespoints
  set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
  plot data u 1:2
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:gnuplot.png]]
```

this results in

```
gnuplot> data = "/tmp/babel-sC46Yh/gnuplot-DvVaqU"
gnuplot> set term png

Terminal type is now 'png'
set output "gnuplot.png"
Options are 'nocrop enhanced size 640,480 font "arial,12.0" '
gnuplot> gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set style data linespoints
gnuplot> set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
gnuplot> plot data u 1:2
         warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
                        ^
         x range is invalid
```

If I manually remove all occurrences of sd from the table a plot gets produces - not what I want but that is a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various places where that could be done, e.g. at the ledger-cli level, you might be able to convince it to skip the `sd` part, or to produce a third column, identical to the second as far as the numbers are concerned but omitting the `sd` part and then having your `gnuplot` block look at columns 1 and 3. Since I don't know much about `ledger`, I will not pursue these further.

Here I'm going to add a source block to transform the input table to the form that the `gnuplot` block expects:

```
#+Name: ledgercli-table
#+RESULTS: LedgerCli
| 2019/12/01 | 12.0 sd |
| 2019/12/03 | -0.5 sd |
| 2019/12/05 | -0.5 sd |
| 2019/12/10 | -1.0 sd |
| 2019/12/17 | -1.0 sd |
| 2020/03/23 | -4.0 sd |
| 2020/04/01 | -0.1 sd |
| 2020/05/19 | -0.5 sd |
| 2020/05/26 | -0.3 sd |

#+begin_src python :var t=ledgercli-table :results output drawer
  print("#+Name: ledger-cli-table-no-currency")
  for l in t:
    print(f"| {l[0]} | {l[1].split(' ')[0]} |")

#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
#+Name: ledger-cli-table-no-currency
| 2019/12/01 | 12.0 |
| 2019/12/03 | -0.5 |
| 2019/12/05 | -0.5 |
| 2019/12/10 | -1.0 |
| 2019/12/17 | -1.0 |
| 2020/03/23 | -4.0 |
| 2020/04/01 | -0.1 |
| 2020/05/19 | -0.5 |
| 2020/05/26 | -0.3 |
:end:

#+begin_src gnuplot :var data=ledger-cli-table-no-currency :file gnuplot.png :exports results
  set xdata time
  set style data linespoints
  set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d"
  plot data u 1:2
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:gnuplot.png]]
```

All you have to do is change the `gnuplot` block to read from the new table. Also, I used a python block to implement the transformation, but it could easily be done in any Org babel-supported language.

Comment: I had to change the code a little because of an old Python on Debian 10


    print(("| {col1} | {col2} |").format( col1=l[0], col2=l[1].split(' ')[0] ))